# Change display via click

Tags: javascript

```
function sg() {
    x = document.getElementById("cai");
    g = x.style.display;
    if (g == "none") {
        g == "block"
    } else {
        g == "none"
    };
}
window.onload = zmena;

function zmena() {
    document.getElementById("matek").onclick = sg;
}
```

Why isnt this script working

Comment: Please create a Fiddle so we can see it failing along side the associated HTML

Comment: Please define "working." What do you expect this script to do? What is it doing instead? Are any errors occurring?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C8w4u/1/ fidlle

Comment: `g` is simply a variable holding the value from `display`, not a pointer to `display`. Even if you hadn't used `==` there, you would not have modified the value of `display`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't assign a value to the variable like that : 'g == "block"' . It is a logical operation, not an assignment. Secondly, you can wrap all if else stuff in one string using the short form, like it is shown below :

```
function sg() {
    x = document.getElementById("cai");
    x.style.display = x.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block'
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answers. People like me downvote answers like this.

Comment: I try to answer the question at first and only after that supply it with details :)

Comment: Okay, but be aware that some people wont wait. They'll simply downvote and leave even if you edit it. Placeholder answers are risky ;)

Answer (score 0):

`g == "block"` and `g == "none"` are comparison operators not assignment operators.

Use `=` not `==` and reference the node not the value of the display property:

```
function sg() {
    x = document.getElementById("cai");
    g = x.style.display;
    if (g == "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    };
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LNd2g/

A better way to code it:

```
function sg () {
    var _element = document.getElementById('cai'), 
        _display = _element.style.display;

    _element.display = (_display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Comment: Works fine, see the demo.

Comment: @user3424358: use `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID` (note the capital "ID" in your fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that to change the style of an element you should `x.style.display = "block"`.
The remaining code seems to be fine.

This seems to be what you need:

```
function sg() {
    var x = document.getElementById("cai");
    var g = x.style.display;

    if (g == "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    };
}

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("matek").onclick = sg;
};
```

Comment: `This seems to be what you need:` does not explain any changes you made. Please explain what's wrong and how you fixed it or you risk downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the script is doing exactly what you're telling it to do, but maybe not what you're expecting it to do.

First problem, as pointed out previously, `==` is a comparison operator, not an assignment operator.  In fact, it's considered bad style to use `==` in most situations, you should use `===` for comparison in javascript.

Second problem, assuming you meant to use the asignment operator where one would expect it, you're modifying a variable `g` to be either "block" or "none", but that will not have any effect `x`'s style.  Also, you should declare your local variables with the `var` keyword, they way you've got it you're creating two globals, `x` and `g`.

Also, I suspect you shouldn't depend on `x.style.display` being `none`, there are a lot of possibilities.  There are more dependable ways to determine if an element is visible or not.

In any case, you probably want something like this:

```
function sg() {
    var x = document.getElementById('cai');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```